# Opening port 8021 in Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, port, hive

I am trying to load data into hive server through a java client, but its throwing exception while loading the data, on checking the hive log I found out the issue is arising because port 8021 is not open. Is there anyway to open the 8021 port, I have the root permission for the system. Thanks

Comment: Do you have SELinux and/or iptables? Are you trying locally or does it go through any routers before? I think you need to provide some more details for us to be able to help you. Not sure if it's on-topic either, seems more fitting for http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use **iptables** command as follows:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8021 -j ACCEPT
```

To save the rule, you also need to issue this:

```
sudo service iptables save
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't save after reboot so use iptables save to save it after reboot too